# Sum columns in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I made a Select on Sqlite3 for my QTableWidget, but when it executes it gets this

`(E.VALOR_VENDA-E.VALOR_CUSTO)` the result in the table is = `"3...."`

and in pure SQL it is correct = "`3.57`"

```
VALOR_VENDA = 5.87
VALOR_CUSTO = 2.3
```

Does anyone know why? I tried to correct but nothing has changed.

[image]

```
        query = """SELECT E.CODBARRA, E.PRODUTO, 
                          C.CATEGORIA, E.ESTOQUE, 
                          E.ESTOQUE_MIN, E.VALOR_CUSTO, 
                          E.VALOR_VENDA, (E.VALOR_VENDA-E.VALOR_CUSTO) AS "LUCRO", 
                          F.FORNECEDOR 
                          FROM ESTOQUE E 
                          INNER JOIN FORNECEDOR F
                          ON E.ID_FORNECEDOR = F.IDFORNECEDOR
                          INNER JOIN CATEGORIA C
                          ON E.ID_CATEGORIA = C.IDCATEGORIA
                          ORDER BY E.PRODUTO"""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite: Get Total/Sum of Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290816/sqlite-get-total-sum-of-column)

Comment: Can you please post your actual `SQL` statement?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query An [mre] for a database question includes a tailored toy database, in the shape of a few lines of `create table ....` and `insert ...`.

Comment: I am trying to sum 2 columns. I will post pictures

Comment: `try decimal(10, 2)` -> `cast(VALOR_VENDA as decimal(10, 2))`

Comment: Not Working Metal

Comment: Work with Printf

Answer (score 0):

Work with Printf

`printf("%.2f",E.VALOR_VENDA-E.VALOR_CUSTO)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems a sqlite issue instead of python ...

The simple [`raise and down`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59661348/7860292) trick should work.